# How to split page into 4 equal parts?

Tags: html, css

I want to divide my page into four equal parts, each of same height and width *(50-50%)*.

I don't want to use JavaScript. I want blocks *(`<div>`s)* to be resized automatically *(and relatively)* if the browser window is resized.

I have not worked with CSS for a long time. I've no idea how to handle this.

Comment: So a 2x2 grid is what you want?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/CRSVU/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#div1 {
  background: #DDD;
}

#div2 {
  background: #AAA;
}

#div3 {
  background: #777;
}

#div4 {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Comment: It does. I just made this in notepad and viewed it using Firefox 15 and it's fine in that. Rebuild it yourself if you like. I think the body tag is handled differently in jsfiddle and maybe the divs require some content.

Comment: Scott is correct, jsfiddle does not render my answer correctly either. However put it in a notepad doc and make a HTML file with it. And should work properly.

Comment: Cheers @thatuxguy. Nice to see a bit of a friendlier response than Curt!

Comment: @ScottBrown np, It's always best to test it locally than via a site like jsfiddle. especially if its only simple HTML/CSS

Comment: To get it to work in jsFiddle, change `body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }` to `html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: Indeed. I keep a skeleton html file ready to help when these little problems arise. JSfiddle's great for testing javascript events but not the best for layout. It's just a testing suite, not a web browser.

Comment: @ScottBrown My apologies Scott, I get frustrated when people post answers which seem to have not been tested. I didn't realise jsfiddle was an exception. I stand corrected!

Comment: @j08691 Nice one, I've updated my jsfiddle to demonstrate this http://jsfiddle.net/BtFNg/1/. +1

Comment: Scott Brown and @thatuxguy, *the original code did **not** work*. You were taking advantage of Quirks Mode, by not putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the file. Throw that DOCTYPE in there, and you'll notice the `html {height:100%;}` is required as well. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @ScottBrown There's a little bit of more problem. I have another element in each of the DIVs. And I want to center them as well (relative to their DIVs height and width). For example, I have this in my 1st div: `<h1> This is DIV 1</h1>`, and so on.

Comment: Loads of info out there on vertical centering, just do a search and I'm sure you'll find what you're after. Just search `vertical centering css` on Google and you'll find all you need, I'm sure

Comment: @ScottBrown Apart from centering, IE is not very happy with this, have you any fix for it.

Comment: Make sure you're using a valid doctype. Perhaps IE is falling back into Quirks Mode.

Comment: @ScottBrown, simple example, works for me..able to integrate with other div containers of mine.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to have control over where they are placed separate from source code order:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

div { position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 50% }

#NW { top: 0;   left: 0;   background: orange }
#NE { top: 0;   left: 50%; background: blue }
#SW { top: 50%; left: 0;   background: green }
#SE { top: 50%; left: 50%; background: red }
```

```html
<div id="NW"></div>
<div id="NE"></div>
<div id="SE"></div>
<div id="SW"></div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmL2W/)

Note: if you want padding on your regions, you'll need to set the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) to `border-box`:

```css
div {
  /* ... */
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

…otherwise your "50%" width and height become "50% + 2em", which will lead to visual overlaps.

Answer (score 5):

Some good answers here but just adding an approach that won't be affected by borders and padding:

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0 }

div { position: absolute; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid #000 }

#nw { background: #f09; top: 0;   left: 0;   right: 50%; bottom: 50% }
#ne { background: #f90; top: 0;   left: 50%; right: 0;   bottom: 50% }
#sw { background: #009; top: 50%; left: 0;   right: 50%; bottom: 0}
#se { background: #090; top: 50%; left: 50%; right: 0;   bottom: 0}
```

```html
<div id="nw">test</div>
<div id="ne">test</div>
<div id="sw">test</div>
<div id="se">test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe how much time I wasted on this. Your solution worked great

Comment: I do have one question why is bottom row bottom=0 and not 100%, same with right column, right = 0 and not 100%. As I said it works, just curious

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to add style to `<body>` tag and `<html>` tag.

```css
.quodrant{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.qtop,
.qbottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
}

.quodrant1,
.quodrant2,
.quodrant3,
.quodrant4{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.quodrant1{
    top: 0;
    left: 50vh;
    background-color: red;
}

.quodrant2{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.quodrant3{
    top: 50vw;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

.quodrant4{ 
    top: 50vw;
    left: 50vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class='quodrant'>
    <div class='qtop'>
        <div class='quodrant1'></div>
        <div class='quodrant2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='qbottom'>
        <div class='quodrant3'></div>
        <div class='quodrant4'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or making it looks nicer.

```css
.quodrant{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.qtop,
.qbottom{
    width: 96%;
    height: 46vh;
}

.quodrant1,
.quodrant2,
.quodrant3,
.quodrant4{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    height: 96%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 2%;
}

.quodrant1{
    background-color: #948be5;
}

.quodrant2{
    background-color: #22e235;
}

.quodrant3{
    background-color: #086e75;
}

.quodrant4{ 
    background-color: #7cf5f9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class='quodrant'>
    <div class='qtop'>
        <div class='quodrant1'></div>
        <div class='quodrant2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='qbottom'>
        <div class='quodrant3'></div>
        <div class='quodrant4'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... obviously you need to set each div to 25%. You then will need to add your content as needed :) Hope that helps.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#top_div {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #009900;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#mid1_div {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #990000;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#mid2_div {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#bottom_div {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #990000;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_div">Top- height is 25% of window height</div>
<div id="mid1_div">Middle 1 - height is 25% of window height</div>
<div id="mid2_div">Middle 2 - height is 25% of window height</div>
<div id="bottom_div">Bottom - height is 25% of window height</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other posts, but with an important distinction to make this work inside a div.  The simpler answers aren't very copy-paste-able because they directly modify div or draw over the entire page.

The key here is that the containing div dividedbox has relative positioning, allowing it to sit nicely in your document with the other elements, while the quarters within have absolute positioning, giving you vertical/horizontal control inside the containing div.

As a bonus, text is responsively centered in the quarters.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Box model</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Title Bar</h1>
  <div id="dividedbox">
    <div class="quarter" id="NW">
      <p>NW</p>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter" id="NE">
      <p>NE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter" id="SE">
      <p>SE</p>
    </div>​
    <div class="quarter" id="SW">
      <p>SW</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height:95%;} /* Important to make sure your divs have room to grow in the document */
#title { background: lightgreen}
#dividedbox { position: relative; width:100%; height:95%}   /* for div growth */
.quarter {position: absolute; width:50%; height:50%;  /* gives quarters their size */
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;} /* centers text */
#NW { top:0;    left:0;     background:orange;     }
#NE { top:0;    left:50%;   background:lightblue;  }
#SW { top:50%;  left:0;     background:green;      }
#SE { top:50%;  left:50%;   background:red;        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/og0j2d3v/