# How to vertically center images of dynamic height inside a div of fixed height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating an image gallery with images of variable heights inside a div of fixed height and width. The height of my parent div is 460px. I want all the images smaller than 460px height aligns vertically in the center of the div.

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var elemst = document.getElementsByName("pictureDiv");
        var img = $('.x-simple img');
        var parentdiv = $('.x-simple');
        for (var i=0;i<elemst.length;i++)
        {
            var ph = parentdiv.height();
            var h = img.height();
            console.log('img height' + h);
            var mh = Math.ceil((ph - h) / 2);

            if(mh>0){
                $('.x-simple img').css('margin-top', mh);
            }
            else
            {
            $('.x-simple img').css('margin-top', 0);
            }
        }
        });
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="x-img-main" src="pic1.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="x-img-main" src="pic2.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="x-img-main" src="pic3.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="x-img-main" src="pic4.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with my code is its giving me only one constant height of 473px if I do a console.log('img height' + h); which is the height of my first image.
Also I can see "margin-top:0px" getting added in all my pictures irrespective of their different heights. Images with smaller heights also gets "margin-top:0px" added to it although it should not happen. Not sure where am I making mistake in my code.

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12284044/939986 (How to split page into 4 equal parts?) without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each()` for iterate over them

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.x-simple').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $img = $this.find('.x-img-main'),
        ph = $this.height(),
        h = $img.height(),
        mh = Math.ceil((ph - h) / 2);
    if (mh > 0) {
      $img.css('margin-top', mh);
    } else {
      $img.css('margin-top', 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="x-img-main" src="pic1.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="x-img-main" src="pic2.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="x-img-main" src="pic3.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 marg-bottom main-img-wrap">
    <div class="xoverlay x-simple" name="pictureDiv">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img class="x-img-main" src="pic4.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Aah I need to add a foreach loop to loop in all the images.Thanks @Pranav C Balan. But one question. I why the for loop that I am using did not work?

Comment: `img.height()` may return height of first image in first div always