# Splitting the HTML page using div

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked quite a few times here. But I'm not very experienced with HTML and am stuck following solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12284044/1330974).

My current implementation is like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/91jjvsk0/). But the problem is if I stretch and adjust the browser window size, the borders of the four equal-sized quadrants follows. What I would like is:

1. The top area would be reserved for a load button and filter boxes.
2. The rest of the area would be divided up into four equally-sized quadrants.
3. When the browser window is adjusted, all five of these areas should not overflow into each other.
4. If I insert `<div>`'s inside each quadrant to draw plots, they should gracefully fall into place and will occupy four equally-sized areas regardless of the browser's size change.

What I'm trying to achieve looks something like in the picture below:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You need to be using flexbox if you want to do this right.

Comment: It looks like bootstrap has been used in your image? The buttons and select field suggest so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide your 4 quadrants into 2 rows.

And give each row `100% width`

and each quadrant a `width of 50%`

also,
make quadrants `float left`.

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.quad {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 49%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select><option>A</option></select>
    <input type="button" value="Filter" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="quad">
  1 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="quad">
  2 of 4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="quad">
  3 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="quad">
  4 of 4
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I have given 49% to quadrants so as to accommodate borders (they have 2 px width [1px each side])

---

You can also do this using flex CSS if you are targetting newer versions of browsers only.

In that case, you do not have to worry about widths.

Just give your row div : `display: flex;`

and your quadrants: `flex: 1 1 auto;`

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) about the flex display.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.quad {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select><option>A</option></select>
    <input type="button" value="Filter" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="quad">
  1 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="quad">
  2 of 4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="quad">
  3 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="quad">
  4 of 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As there is no "flexing" involved in this layout, you could also use `display: grid`, which was build solely for layouts like this. If you want more info on that I'll provide an answer. Further [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Comment: @Himanshu Tyagi, Thank you for showing two possible approaches and sharing the resources about 'flex'. Your suggested solution works and I'm going to accept this because of it is comprehensive and it was submitted earlier than others. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using bootstrap 4 you can easily create such an layout. Bootstrap makes it much easier for developers to create a layout.

If you wanna use bootstrap, you can do following. Bootstrap 4 uses `flexbox` instead of `float` which is `+1` comparing to bootstrap 3.

```css
.vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.choose-plot {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.bordered {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column vh-100">
    <!-- I want this container to stretch to the height of the parent -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col choose-plot">
        <strong class="mb-2">Add/remove COUNTRIES (max: 5), ADVERTISES (max 4), YEAR (max 1), and plot location below. Then, click 'load plot'.</strong>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                <select class="custom-select">
                  <option>Choose plot</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Load plot</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-6 bordered">1 of 4</div>
        <div class="col-6 bordered">2 of 4</div>
        <div class="col-6 bordered">3 of 4</div>
        <div class="col-6 bordered">4 of 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution actually is slightly different than the others because it adjusts the size of the elements within to the size of the browser window until it gives in and shows the scroll bars. I really like it, but accepted the one submitted earlier because it worked (albeit in a different way) as well.

Comment: No problem, you are the OP and decide which anwser fits best ;)

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question [https://stackoverflow.com/q/50849825/1330974] related to the answer you've provided above. I'm hoping that you could take a look and suggestion. :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Dividing into rows too,

I suggest you to use `box-sizing: border-box;` so that when you set `width` to `50%`, the borders sizes are taken into account.

```css
.col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>Something here.</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that your suggested solution works. :)