# Using Bootstrap 4 flexbox to equally divide four charts

Tags: css, html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to plot four different stacked charts in one browser window as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tzao357v/4/). But as it is, the size of the charts aren't equal. I have tried tweaking various CSS properties, but being unfamiliar with CSS+HTML layout, I wasn't able to.

Any suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

All of my code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/autocomplete-0.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
        .custom-select-lg {
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            height: 52px;
            padding: 0 0 0 15px;
            font-size: 125%;
            width: 290px;
        }
        .vh-100 {
          min-height: 100vh;
        }

        .choose-plot {
          padding-top: 15px;
          padding-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .bordered {
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 10px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column vh-100">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col choose-plot">
                <strong class="mb-2">Instruction here</strong>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-1">
                        <button id="load_plot" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Load plot</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-6 bordered">1 of 4
                    <div id="container-0" style="height: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 bordered">2 of 4
                    <div id="container-1" style="height: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 bordered">3 of 4
                    <div id="container-2" style="height: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 bordered">4 of 4
                    <div id="container-3" style="height: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/echarts-4.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var doms = [
            document.getElementById("container-0"),
            document.getElementById("container-1"),
            document.getElementById("container-2"),
            document.getElementById("container-3"),
        ];
        var myCharts = [];
        var myOption = {
            tooltip : {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer : {
                    type : 'shadow'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                data: ['直接访问', '邮件营销','联盟广告','视频广告','搜索引擎']
            },
            grid: {
                left: '3%',
                right: '4%',
                bottom: '3%',
                containLabel: true
            },
            xAxis:  {
                type: 'category',
                data: ['周一','周二','周三','周四','周五','周六','周日']
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value'
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: '直接访问',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
                },
                {
                    name: '邮件营销',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
                },
                {
                    name: '联盟广告',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
                },
                {
                    name: '视频广告',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [150, 212, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
                },
                {
                    name: '搜索引擎',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [820, 832, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
                }
            ]
        }; //myOption ends
        $('#load_plot').on('click', function() {
            if (myCharts.length != 0) {
                myCharts.forEach(function (c) {
                    c.dispose();
                });
            }
            doms.forEach(function(ele){
                var curChart = echarts.init(ele, null, {renderer: 'canvas'});
                curChart.showLoading();
                curChart.setOption(curOption = myOption);
                curChart.hideLoading();
                console.log("done loading");
                myCharts.push(curChart);

            });
        });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan Thank you for chiming in. I just wanted to make sure the resulting plots occupy the full height and width in the respective cards (1, 2, 3 and 4) that are designed to occupy four equal quadrants of the `<div class="row flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start">`. In other words, the plots should be of equal size instead of the current state (when you click 'Load plot' button, you'll see what I mean). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try giving height of 45vh to the class bordered i.e.,
`.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 45vh;
}`

Comment: One more thing is that You have been calling unnecessary extra classes in the div's. Make sure to remove them.

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/tzao357v/44/). I have intended the code and removed extra unnecessary classes and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove inline height of 100% from the div just inside `.col-6.bordered` and add the following style.

```
.col-6.bordered > div {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

```css
.col-6.bordered>div {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .custom-select-lg {
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      height: 52px;
      padding: 0 0 0 15px;
      font-size: 125%;
      width: 290px;
    }
    
    .vh-100 {
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .choose-plot {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .bordered {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column vh-100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col choose-plot">
        <strong class="mb-2">Instruction here</strong>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1">
            <button id="load_plot" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Load plot</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start">
      <div class="col-6 bordered">1 of 4
        <div id="container-0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 bordered">2 of 4
        <div id="container-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 bordered">3 of 4
        <div id="container-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 bordered">4 of 4
        <div id="container-3" "></div>
            </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js " integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin=" anonymous "></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js " integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9 " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts-en.js "></script>
<script>


  var doms = [
      document.getElementById("container-0 "),
      document.getElementById("container-1 "),
            document.getElementById("container-2 "),
            document.getElementById("container-3 "),
        ];
  var myCharts = [];
  var myOption = {
            tooltip : {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer : {
                    type : 'shadow'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                data: ['直接访问', '邮件营销','联盟广告','视频广告','搜索引擎']
            },
            grid: {
                left: '3%',
                right: '4%',
                bottom: '3%',
                containLabel: true
            },
            xAxis:  {
                type: 'category',
                data: ['周一','周二','周三','周四','周五','周六','周日']
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value'
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: '直接访问',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
                },
                {
                    name: '邮件营销',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
                },
                {
                    name: '联盟广告',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
                },
                {
                    name: '视频广告',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [150, 212, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
                },
                {
                    name: '搜索引擎',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'a',
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'insideRight'
                        }
                    },
                    data: [820, 832, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
                }
            ]
        }; //myOption ends
  $('#load_plot').on('click', function() {
            if (myCharts.length != 0) {
                myCharts.forEach(function (c) {
                    c.dispose();
                });
            }
            doms.forEach(function(ele){
                var curChart = echarts.init(ele, null, {renderer: 'canvas'});
                curChart.showLoading();
                curChart.setOption(curOption = myOption);
                curChart.hideLoading();
                console.log("done loading ");
                myCharts.push(curChart);

            });
  });
  
  </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzao357v/26/)

Answer (score 1):

The default definition is `min-height:1px`
 whats mean that the `height` will be **automatic** as the `height` of the content
For provide  it you can set `height: 100vh;`

```
.bordered{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggested solution works, but since Nandita's solution also works and s/he submitted a bit earlier, I've accepted that as a solution. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: fine:) happy to help