# Page deviation into 4 parts H Layout css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I am trying to make an H page layout:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.b {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.c {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.d {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  text
</div>
<div class="b">
  text
</div>
<div class="c">
  text
</div>
<div class="d">
  text
</div>
```

but for some reason my last div goes to the bottom 
I was curious if I can do what I want but on flexbox so I tried this as well

[How to split page into 4 equal parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284044/how-to-split-page-into-4-equal-parts)

http://jsfiddle.net/scriv/ye6bd4ow/4/

```
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

div {
 float: left;
}

#div1 {
 background: #DDD;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
}

#div2 {
 background: #AAA;
 width: 60%;
 height: 60%;
}

#div3 {
 background: #777;
 width: 60%;
 height: 40%;
}

#div4 {
 float: right;
 background: #444;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
}

<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
<div id="div3">
</div>
<div id="div4">
</div>
```

Same result but I think a little closer than the 1st example

I know this is a very controversial question but any help even an opinion of which approach u think is best is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I advise you to don't pay much attention to questions before 2016, and to don't look for so specific questions. Just learn how these properties work, what's CSS and how it works and how to build basic layouts. I think it can be solved with a couple of classes using flexbox or grid-laoyut

Comment: @CristianTraìna I will get on it right ahead. Any content u think is best?

Comment: I used the scrimba [flexbox tutorial](https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox) and [grid layout tutorial](https://scrimba.com/g/gR8PTE). But I don't know if there's something better around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues to fix (if you want the float version to work):

1.) You need to use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the border in the width measurement, otherwise (see your snippet) the fourth element will slip below the third one since there isn't enough space for it (only by a few pixels, but nevertheless).

2.) You need to change the order in the HTML: d should be the third element so that it can be at the top of the page/container:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.b {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.c {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.d {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  text a 
</div>
<div class="b">
  text b
</div>
<div class="d">
  text d
</div>
<div class="c">
  text c 
</div>
```